# Android: canvas gives null pointer exception - How can fix it?

Tags: android, pointers, canvas, android-asynctask, null

I'm doing a joystick application where a button click should display a list view. However, when i open the list view the application shuts down with an error message about canvas having a null pointer exception and therefore cant get width/height of the canvas.
error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Canvas.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

the code:

```
public class MySurfaceThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    CustomSurfaceView cSurfaceView;


    public MySurfaceThread(SurfaceHolder sh, CustomSurfaceView csv){
        mSurfaceHolder = sh;
        cSurfaceView = csv;
        x = y = 0;

        cSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                System.out.println(x + " " + y);

                calculateValues(x,y);

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        x = y = 0;
                        dx = dy = 0;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }

            private void calculateValues(float xx, float yy){
                dx = xx-zeroX;
                dy = yy-zeroY;
                angle = (float)Math.atan(Math.abs(dy / dx));
                c = (float)Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

                if(c > radius){
                    if (dx > 0 && dy > 0) { //lower right corner
                        xx = (float) (zeroX + radius * Math.cos(angle));
                        yy = (float) (zeroY + radius * Math.sin(angle));
                    }
                    else if(dx > 0 && dy < 0){ //top right corner
                        xx = (float) (zeroX + radius * Math.cos(angle));
                        yy = (float) (zeroY - radius * Math.sin(angle));
                    }
                    else if(dx < 0 && dy < 0){ //top left corner
                        xx = (float) (zeroX - radius * Math.cos(angle));
                        yy = (float) (zeroY - radius * Math.sin(angle));
                    }
                    else if(dx < 0 && dy > 0){ //lower left corner
                        xx = (float) (zeroX - radius * Math.cos(angle));
                        yy = (float) (zeroY + radius * Math.sin(angle));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    xx = zeroX + dx;
                    yy = zeroY + dy;
                }
                System.out.println("dx: " + dx);
                System.out.println("dy: " + dy);
                x = xx;
                y = yy;
            }
        });


    }


    //@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        while(run) {



            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.drawBitmap(background,0,0,null);
            cSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(mSurfaceHolder);



            try {

                canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {

                    zeroX = (1704-1704/8);
                    zeroY = (915-915/4);
                    cSurfaceView.onDraw(canvas, x, y, zeroX, zeroY);

                }
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also, if needed - heres the onDraw method:

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas, float x, float y, float zx, float zy){

    dx = x-zx;
    dy = y-zy;

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);
    canvas.drawBitmap(background, (canvas.getWidth() - canvas.getWidth() / 7) - background.getWidth() / 2, (canvas.getHeight() - canvas.getHeight() / 4) - background.getHeight() / 2, null);
    canvas.drawText(Float.toString(x), 60, 60, paint1);
    canvas.drawText(Float.toString(y), 60, 120, paint1);

    if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, (canvas.getWidth()-canvas.getWidth() / 7) - ball.getWidth() / 2, (canvas.getHeight()-canvas.getHeight() / 4) - ball.getHeight() / 2, null);

    }
    else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, x - ball.getWidth() / 2, y - ball.getHeight() / 2, null);
    }
}
```

Do you guys have any idea how i can initialize the canvas in order for it to work?

Appreciate all the help i can get!

Comment: According to the docs:   A null is returned if the surface has not been created or otherwise cannot be edited. You will usually need to implement Callback.surfaceCreated to find out when the Surface is available for use.   Either its been destroyed on not yet created.  You should not run this thread until the surface is ready, and kill it when the surface is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @gabesechan,
I'm still not really sure how to check if the surface has been created. 
So far I've tried doing the following in the Callback.surfaceCreated:
    
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        Surface surface = arg0.getSurface();

        if (arg0 != null){
            thread.execute();
        }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gabe's explanation i got it to work with the following code for the Callback.

```
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    Surface surface = arg0.getSurface();


    if (surface != null){
        thread.execute((Void[])null);
    }


}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

    thread.cancel(true);

}
```

By following the comments, I implemented a way for the thread to execute when the surface is created and as soon as it is destroyed(in this case when a new frame opens) the thread is cancelled.

Cheers!